# What's the best way to pattern match a specific element at any position in a list?

Tags: ocaml

Say I have some lists

`["a"; "b"; "d"]`
`["a"; "c"; "d"]`

The elements may be in any order. The lists will contain one of `"b"` or `"c"` but never both.

I want to return a particular value if `"b"` is in the list, or a different value if `"c"` is in the list.

I'm new to OCaml but so far as I can tell this is not possible via pattern matching, or have I missed something?

What would be the most idiomatic recipe for doing this?

Comment: Just to be clear, do your lists have an arbitrary length?

Comment: For what I'm doing right now they'll always be length=3, but I was trying to avoid writing out all the possible pattern matches

Comment: You aren't clear abut what case you want to test for. If you want to test whether a list contains `"c"` you can use `List.mem "c" list`. It seems like more of an `if` statement thing than a pattern matching thing, as you say.

Comment: Ah sorry, I deleted part of my question by mistake. Yes, that's how I would do it in Python... I just wondered if there was a less imperative way

Comment: If all your lists are of length at most 3, then there aren’t many patterns to write. `(match my_list with "b"::_ | _::"b"::_ | _::_::"b"::_ -> true | _ -> false)`. But for such small lengths you can just as well use `List.mem` as Jeffrey said (see my answer for why that’s not ideal for this task with longer lists).

Comment: @Anentropic “I just wondered if there was a less imperative way”: there isn’t anything imperative about `if List.mem "b" my_list then … else …`. No mutation, no side effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are given an unknown list, which you know contains either `"b"` or `"c"`, but not both, and you want to determine which is the case. And perhaps even find the position of the first occurrence?

That’s an interesting question. First you can of course write the loop by hand:

```ml
let rec find_b_or_c i = function
| []                    -> raise Not_found (* assumed not to happen ? *)
| (("b"|"c") as x) :: _ -> (i, x)
| _ :: xs               -> find_b_or_c (i+1) xs
in
let (i, x) = find_b_or_c 0 my_list in
(* … do something with the index and/or the letter
     (for instance test whether x = "b") … *)
```

Then the question is whether you can write it more concisely / elegantly by combining existing functions. If you are not interested in the index, you can simply use `List.find` or its variant returning an option:

```ml
let x = List.find (fun x -> x = "b" || x = "c") my_list in (* … *)
```

You might also test membership of, say, `"b"`, with `List.mem` (or more generally `List.exists`); however with that approach, the search won’t be short-circuited as soon as the list contains a `"c"` (with a very long list which has a `"c"` at the beginning but no `"b"`, you’ll waste a lot of time).

However, there is no way to get the index with [the standard functions](https://ocaml.org/api/List.html), because none of them return an index. This is deliberate, because list indexing is slow (linear time) and you shouldn’t do it. If you really want the index, you’d have to use the manual recursion above, or perhaps write a more generic function `find_with_index`.